# Bootstrap 4 - 3 cols in row with different widths that don't stack when screen gets smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

This may have been posted already but I can't find it. I'm trying to get 3 columns in a row to get smaller (50% middle column and 25% left and right) instead of stacking on top of each other like bootstrap already does with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      25%
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      50%
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      25%
    </div>
</div>
```

Does bootstrap's grid system support this or do I have to do it myself?

Comment: these ones will never stack on each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [auto-layout cols](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width), and combine it with the pre-defined grid.

> Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns also means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it.

https://www.codeply.com/go/XwEJzauAam

`col-6` == 50%

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      25%
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      50%
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      25%
    </div>
</div>
```

These `col` and `col-*` **will NOT stack**.

The stacking (responsive) columns (by breakpoint) are..

`col-sm` and `col-sm-*` - 576px
`col-md` and `col-md-*` - 768px
`col-lg` and `col-lg-*` - 992px
`col-xl` and `col-xl-*` - 1200px

Comment: And since it's a 12 grid system, the other col's should be col-3. Also you need to specify on which screens, like this on small screens col-sm-3.

Comment: No, I don't. Read about [auto layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width).

Comment: @MarcHjorthLaustsen V4 is mobile first so this work on mobile and above

Comment: Thanks but with their grid system, the columns stack on top of each other when the screen is smaller but I'm trying to get them to be all in a row no matter the screen size ----- never mind this I forgot to add something

Comment: I was confused because I have a container inside the middle column, which isn't being responsive like the content in the top and bottom ones.